# Dockerfile COPY command stops working when I change the FROM image

Tags: docker

I have two custom images. One is for developing websites using next.js and the other is to develop APIs.

My `company/site` image is like:

```
FROM node:lts-bullseye-slim

# the rest of it
```

And my `company/api` image is like:

```
ARG VARIANT="6.0-bullseye-slim"
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/vscode/devcontainers/dotnet:${VARIANT}

# the rest of it
```

The problem is that, the `COPY` commands works when I use `company/api` as my `FROM` image, but fails when I use `company/site`.

In other words, this works:

```
FROM company/api

COPY . .

RUN /buildScript.sh
```

But for the same directory, the same context, the same everything, this fails:

```
FROM compnay/site

COPY . .

RUN /buildScript.sh
```

In other words, `COPY` copies no file to the image. Everything is the same. There is no `.dockerignore` file. The same directory, the same context, the same syntax `docker build -t company/api-or-site .`

The only thing that causes this fail, is changing the base image.

What can cause this error? How can I debug this?

Comment: It would be very helpful if you could [edit] the question to include a [mcve].  What other setup is done in those base images?  How exactly do you tell the `COPY` doesn't have an effect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After spending days on this, I finally realized what the problem was.

When you create a custom image using a `Dockerfile`, if you use the `WORKDIR` command, then that would be the `.` in your future `COPY` commands.

Consider the following image:

```
FROM node:lts-bullseye-slim

# Your specific commands

WORKDIR /project
```

Let's say you build this image and tag it `company/node`.

Now if you want to use it as the base image for another image, and `COPY . .` files, then those files would be copied to the `/project` directory.

```
FROM company/node

COPY . . # here, the second dot means the relative path inside the company/node image
```